# Maximum of $\frac{a_1}{a_2}+\frac{a_2}{a_3}+\cdots+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}$ for $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ a permutation of $1,2,\ldots,n$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> If $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ is a permutation of $1,2,\ldots,n$, where
>   $n\geq4$, find the maximum of
>   $$\frac{a_1}{a_2}+\frac{a_2}{a_3}+\cdots+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}.$$

By the results of running computer programs, the condition for equality is something like $$(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=(n-1,2,n-3,4,\ldots,n-2,3,n,1).$$ Yet this is so strange that I don't know how to obtain it; what kind of inequalities lead to such kind of condition for equality? Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Cjeck the rearrangement inequality, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality)

Comment: @Andreas The maximum is $\frac{n}{1}+\frac{n-1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{4}{n-5}+\frac{7}{n-4}+\frac{2}{n-3}+\frac{5}{n-2}+\frac{3}{n}$. The rearrangement inequality does not lead to such an upper bound.

Comment: @YuxiaoXie I am unsure how to fill the "$\ldots$" in your guess for the max value. Also, the permutation in your post looks like working for even $n$ as mixing the odd numbers going down and the even numbers going up. But then consecutive terms would always add up to $n\pm1$, so the end might at most be $\ldots, 3, n-2,1,n$. (And in that case, the permutation does not seem to be optimal)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The systematics is: $a_{2i} = 2i$ and $a_{2i+1} = n - 2i - 1$.

Comment: @Andreas I don't think your systematics is correct, since $a_n=1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen This formula is obtained from computer programs. The "$\ldots$" is actually not approariate, because the systematics is not consistent. The condition for equailty for $n=4,5,6,7$ are as follows: $(3,2,4,1)$, $(4,2,3,5,1)$, $(5,2,4,3,6,1)$, $(6,2,5,4,3,7,1)$.